# SQL query (can include pl/sql bits) based on conditional count

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

Premise: We've got a table with 5 fields. 2 fields are always unique.

What would be a good way to fulfill this:

if (count_of_result  ==  3) {
  add up the 3 rows from the same table. unique values get added up & the non-unique       values are assumed to be same for all the 3 rows. 
  the query result should show 1 row, with the values added up.
}
else
{

display all the results of the query as usual.

}

Thank you.

Comment: Read about how to use `GROUP BY` and `SUM(field)` function.

Comment: `SELECT a,b,c, SUM(d), SUM(e) FROM tableT GROUP BY a,b,c ;` , where `d,e` are the unique fields.

Comment: that sounds good. what about the 'count condition', we'll need to do the sum and the group by only if the count was 3 or less.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want the result to be shown if table has exactly 3 rows? And if not (if it has less than or more than 3), then the query to show what, all rows of table without any grouping and summing?

Comment: yes, the result with the sum() [single row] will be shown only if the table has 3 rows or less, and if it has more, then the result should contain all the rows [4+ of them] without any sum() done to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably more efficient ways for this:

```
SELECT a,b,c, SUM(d) AS d, SUM(e) AS e 
  FROM tableT 
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableT) <= 3
  GROUP BY a,b,c 
UNION ALL
SELECT a,b,c,d,e 
  FROM tableT 
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableT) > 3
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a, b, c, sum(d), sum(e) from (
    select a, b, c,
           case count(*) over(partition by a, b, c)
           when 3 then null else rownum end as group_controller
    from tableT
) group by a, b, c, group_controller;
```

I think this should work.  The analytical function contained in the inline view determines whether there will be exactly 3 rows in a group (without aggregating).  The outer query's group by requires do_group to be null (or whatever constant value) in cases where grouping should be performed (thus deferring to a & b for grouping), or a unique value when grouping should be neutralized (rownum will do nicely in this situation).

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, I feel this is pretty close to the final solution.  though, isn't "partition by" specific to t-sql?  Also, would the sum(d) and sum(e) work in the given solution?